# angularjs $compile is not working on production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am using angularJS in my MVC application and loading a partial using ajax call in angularJS. I am using $compile to compile the html. Everything is working fine on local but it is not working on production. Unexpected error is showing. Below is the code I am using.

Angular Controller:

```
    app.controller("mproductController", ["$scope", "mproductService", "$compile", function ($scope, mproductService, $compile) {
$scope.ShowProdUnitPop = function (val) {
    mproductService.ShowProdUnitPop(val).success(function (result) {
        debugger;
        var snippet = angular.element(result);
        $compile(snippet)($scope);
        $("#dvAddProd").html(snippet);
        $("#dvPopup").modal('show');
    });
}
}
```

Angular Service:

```
app.service("mproductService", ["$http", function ($http) {
this.ShowProdUnitPop = function () {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/Home/GetActiveCat"
    });
    return request;
}}
```

MVC Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddProduct(int id)
    {

        ViewBag.ProductCategory = Utility.GetProd(id);
        return PartialView("_AddProduct",new Product());
    }
```

Error is throwing on this line:

```
     var snippet = angular.element(result);
        $compile(snippet)($scope);
        $("#dvAddProd").html(snippet);
        $("#dvPopup").modal('show');
```

It is working on local but not on production. Please help.

Comment: could you add whole code where you used `$compile` service? I think its controller..

Comment: @pankajparkar: Edited controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using bundling and minification enabled on production server. That is breaking you controller code while you are utilizing that controller and its necessary to have inline array annotation of DI while minifying JS files.

Most possible answer would be you are using `$compile` by injecting it to controller and using it, That's fine. It seems like you had not followed inline array dependency injection inside your controller.

Also you need to attach compile element to your `dvAddProd` element, rather than updating `html`, appending html to DOM will never make angular angular binding on that element. Looks like this code shouldn't be working on any of the environment if it has angular bindings on it.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('someCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile',
    function($scope, $http, $compile) {
        //you should have controller in this way that would fix your issue
        //note I'm using inline array notation of DI
        $scope.ShowProdUnitPop = function(val) {
            mproductService.ShowProdUnitPop(val).success(function(result) {
                debugger;
                var snippet = angular.element(result);
                var compiledSnippet = $compile(snippet)($scope);
                $("#dvAddProd").append(compiledSnippet); //should attach compile element
            });
        }
    }
]);
```

Visit [**this link**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) for more Information

Comment: I am doing exactly as you are suggesting. It is working fine at local but on production it is creating problem.

Comment: @Big could you please add you controller code?..please update in your question